# Custom Error messages in Exim

Tags: exim

Can anyone know how to change default error messages generated by exim for Unrouteable address or quota exceeded?

I found this "[Customizing error messages](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-3.20/doc/html/spec_39.html)" , but I don't know how to use it...

Where to save these files?

What is the meaning of `>>>>>>> .linelength 80em` ? can/need I change it?

-- My exim version is 4.84.2 on Debian 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was take wrong documentation version.
I set `bounce_message_file` to file contains template in format from this:
[exim documentation 4.84](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-4.84/doc/html/spec_html/ch-customizing_bounce_and_warning_messages.html) and its working perfect.